# Rviz odometry is all yellow

Tags: navigation, odometry, visual-odometry, rviz, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys!
I have a problem in displaying odometry in Rviz.
I use robot localization to fuse odometry from wheels and visual odometry from Kinect. When I turn on visualization in Rviza all screen seems to be yellow. And after several moves it totaly paints all with yellow colour.

[image: image description]

I disabled tf from wheel odometry and from visual odometry. Only robot_localization provides tf with odom.
Here is my robot_localization launch.

```
<launch>
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization" clear_params="true">

  <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odom" />

  <param name="frequency" value="30"/>  
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.1"/>  

  <param name="two_d_mode" value="false"/>
  <param name="transform_time_offset" value="0.0"/>

  <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
  <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
  <param name="world_frame" value="odom"/>

  <param name="odom0" value="odom_base"/>
   <param name="odom1" value="odom_visual"/>

  <rosparam param="odom0_config">[true, true, false,  
                                  false, false, true, 
                                  false, false, false,   
                                  false, false, true,
                                  false, false, false]</rosparam>

  <rosparam param="odom1_config">[false, false, false, 
                                  false, false, false, 
                                  true, true, false,   
                                  false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false]</rosparam>

  <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
<param name="odom1_differential" value="false"/>

  <param name="odom0_relative" value="false"/>
<param name="odom1_relative" value="false"/> 

  <param name="use_odometry_yaw" value="false"/>-->

  <param name="debug"           value="false"/>
  <param name="debug_out_file"  value="debug_ukf_localization.txt"/>

  <param name="alpha" value="0.001"/> 
  <param name="kappa" value="0"/> 

  <param name="beta" value="2"/>

</node>
 
</launch>
```

And in addition odom that I get is very inaccurate.
So what's problem? Why everything is yellow?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282512/rviz-odometry-is-all-yellow/) by [Andrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/32433/andrey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2018-02-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-13**:
Odometry arrows can be yellow, that is normal. Can you check whether the scaling is off? Try zooming out (mouse scrollwheel) very far. Perhaps the arrows are just *really* big, and the RViz view is rendered from *inside* the arrow.

**Comment by [Andrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/32433/andrey/) on 2018-02-14**:
Yes. I just zoomed out and saw what was not right. I removed check mark from "covariance" in odom display and it work ok.
Thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
Disabling `covariance` rendering is *not* a solution. What you're seeing could indicate that your covariances are way too large. That would not just be a visualisation problem, but a problem in general.

I would suggest you try to figure out where those covariances are coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A few things:

1. I'm guessing the yellow in rviz is the massive covariance (probably rotational). If you uncheck the `Covariance` checkbox under your `rviz` `Odometry` display, it'll likely go away.
2. Thanks for posting your launch file. However, I can't make any comment regarding "why is the filter doing XYZ?" unless I have sample input messages from all of your sensors.
3. I note that you have a hanging XML comment tag next to `use_odometry_yaw`
4. Do both of your `odom` input sources exist in the same coordinate frame? You are fusing both absolutely.
5. You have `two_d_mode` set to *false*, but are fusing only 2D variables. This will make your covariance for `Z`, `roll`, and `pitch` (as well as their velocities) explode.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/32433/andrey/) on 2018-02-19**:
Thanks, Tom!
How can I check if both of odoms exit in the same coordinate frames?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2018-02-26**:
Visualize them both at the same time . If they are always pretty much in agreement, you're fine. If they start to diverge (e.g., the headings start to differ, or they move apart from each other), then you need make one of them `differential`.